# customer quote get inactive automatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2

i am using magento 2.3.4 and my quote is getting inactive automatically after some time.
in

`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart`
Quote Lifetime set as 30 days. but quote get inactive before 30 days only.

what are all the scenario to make it inactive?

Answer (score 0):

It's a default in Magento. For more information about that configuration you can follow this [Quote Lifetime in Magento 2](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/sales/cart-quote-lifetime.html) .

If you are looking for code then following file will help you.

**File Name :** vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Collection/ExpiredQuotesCollection.php
**Method Name :** getExpiredQuotes()

If this help you in building your logic then hit like.

Thank you
Hiren Patel